# Is this correct usage of builder pattern in dtos?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

Assume i have PostDTO that has this fields:

```
private Long id;
private ShortInfoUserDTO author;
private CategoryDTO category;
```

And i have CategoryDTO inside of it that also has Builder, and it has fields:

```
private Long id;
private String name;
```

And ShortInfoUserDTO has some fields (doesn't matter what fields, but it also has Builder)

And My builder pattern looks like this ( both CategoryDTO and

```
public static Builder builder() {
    return new PostDTO.Builder();
}
public static class Builder {
    PostDTO instance = new PostDTO();        

    public Builder id(Long id) {
        instance.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder author(User user) {
        ShortInfoUserDTO author = ShortInfoUserDTO.builder()
                                                  .id(user.getId())
                                            .username(user.getUsername())
                                            .build();
        instance.author = author;
        return this;
    }



    public Builder category(Category category) {
          CategoryDTO categoryDto = CategoryDTO
                                      .builder()
                                      .id(category.getId())
                                      .name(category.getName())
                                      .build();           

          instance.category = categoryDto;            
          return this;
    }

    public PostDTO build() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Is generally the idea of building author() and category() this way good? like is this proper architecture? One of the reason im asking is because i'm kinda worried about nullpointerexceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yeah, it is a quite neat way for building your POJO's as long as you can live with this amount of boilerplate code.

[Lombok builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) can help you reduce the amount of boilerplate.

Another approach is using a mapping tool instead of manual `DTO` construction. Have a look on [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org) for instance.

With mapper you can do something like this:

```
public class So44937295ApplicationTests {
    final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    @Test
    public void manual() {
        final User user = new User();
        user.setId(42L);
        user.setUsername("John");
        user.setPassword("goof");

        final Category category = new Category();
        category.setId(23L);
        category.setName("Category 1");

        final PostDTO postDTO = new PostDTO();
        postDTO.setAuthor(modelMapper.map(user, ShortInfoUserDTO.class));
        postDTO.setCategory(modelMapper.map(category, CategoryDTO.class));

        assertEquals(user.getId(), postDTO.getAuthor().getId());
        assertEquals(user.getUsername(), postDTO.getAuthor().getUsername());

        assertEquals(category.getId(), postDTO.getCategory().getId());
        assertEquals(category.getName(), postDTO.getCategory().getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void auto() {
        final User user = new User();
        user.setId(42L);
        user.setUsername("John");
        user.setPassword("goof");

        final Category category = new Category();
        category.setId(23L);
        category.setName("Category 1");

        class Post {
            private User author;
            private Category category;
            // getters and setters
        }

        final Post post = new Post();
        post.setAuthor(user);
        post.setCategory(category);
        final PostDTO postDTO = modelMapper.map(post, PostDTO.class);

        assertEquals(post.getAuthor().getId(), postDTO.getAuthor().getId());
        assertEquals(post.getAuthor().getUsername(), postDTO.getAuthor().getUsername());

        assertEquals(post.getCategory().getId(), postDTO.getCategory().getId());
        assertEquals(post.getCategory().getName(), postDTO.getCategory().getName());
    }

    public static class PostDTO {
        private Long id;
        private ShortInfoUserDTO author;
        private CategoryDTO category;
        // getters and setters
    }

    public static class User {
        private Long id;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        // getters and setters
    }

    public static class ShortInfoUserDTO {
        private Long id;
        private String username;
        // getters and setters
    }

    public static class Category {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        // getters and setters
    }

    public static class CategoryDTO {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        // getters and setters
    }

}
```

And all transformation logic will be done for you using reflection (based on field names). You can configure that behavior.